# Cursor is always crosshair in D3 due to slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cursor

I'd like to change my cursor, which is always "crosshair" when hovering over my D3 visualization. I don't have any JS, D3 og CSS code that should change the cursor to "crosshair". I've tried `d3.select("body").style("cursor", "default");` and
`html, body {cursor: "default";}`, but nothing seems to work. Is this a common problem?

**EDIT:** I've found that it's likely due to my use of a slider/brush. See http://jsfiddle.net/0ukesgaw/.

**Updated jsfiddle. Still not working.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a common problem AFAIK. It would be easier to help if you provided a code sample. It's generally a better approach to apply the CSS for the cursor on the d3 visualization itself, not "globally" on the `html` or `body` elements.

CSS example:

```
svg {
  cursor: default;
}
```

**Update 1:**

I inspected the elements using Chrome’s dev tools (right-click > Inspect element) and found this:

```
<rect class="background" x="0" width="200" height="210" 
  style="visibility: hidden; cursor: crosshair;"></rect>
```

Which means that the `cursor: crosshair` is somehow applied to this element. I can't see it anywhere in your source code, so I suppose it's something that d3 adds – so you were right in your original question.

A quickfix for this, would be to add:

```
svg rect.background {
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

However, it's probably worth taking the time to find the source code that generates it, if this is going to be in production.

**Update 2:**

Looking closer at this, it seems to come from d3's Brush component: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush

This is from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/brush.js:

```
  background.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("cursor", "crosshair");
```

Looks like you need to go with something like `cursor: default !important` :-/

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! I've tried copying brush.js and make my own version `my_brush.js` with all the code related to the cursor commented out, but it doesn't work as it can't access all of the private methods in D3. What would the cursor look like if I had two cursors set with !important?

Comment: Happy to help. This jsfiddle uses `cursor: default !important`:  
http://jsfiddle.net/0ukesgaw/2/